# Disabling div based on condition in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having an ng-repeat that repeats n times..

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<fieldset ng-disabled="item.activityId==lockResourceId">
<div>Hello</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
onWebSocketFired();
  function onWebSocketFired(isLock){
        $scope.lockResourceId=isLock;
}
```

Here each time the function onWebSocketFired() is fired with the **lockResourceId** and if that is equals to **item.activityId** then the div will be disabled.
Now this happens for one div inside the ng-repeat on each of the onWebSocketFired() call.But I would like to keep the previously disabled field as it is until and unless any other call has been called.
Can anyone suggest a fix please?

Comment: not sure I got the problem, you are using `=` instead of `==` to initialize the value, right?

Comment: Try `item.activityId == lockResourceId`

Comment: This will disable the current div based on the lockResourceId and item.activityId.I want to keep the disabled div's that are from the previous lockResourceId

Comment: Why are you storing it in *one* variable in that case and not an array of `lockedResourceIds`?

Comment: I tried like that but was not sure how to use it in the HTMl? ng-disabled condition

Comment: in your controller scope there is a single copy of  `lockResourceId `, which is overwritten every time with `isLock` value. so what you can do is to create a new variable `lockResourceId` for every item in `items` using current index, this way values will not overlap & change the condition in binding to `ng-disabled="item.activityId==item.lockResourceId"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to keep previously disabled fieldsets disabled when new one gets disabled too, you want to store `lockResourceId` in form of array or object.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <fieldset ng-disabled="lockResourceId[item.activityId]">
    <div>Hello {{ item.activityId }}</div>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Then in controller you would use it like this:

```
$scope.lockResourceId = {};

// Lock some id
$scope.lockResourceId[id] = isLock;
```